# How to calculate the number of visible columns in a MSFLEXGRID

Tags: vb6, msflexgrid

How Do I calculate the number of visible columns in a MSFLEXGRID in characters in VB6?
I have the form ScaleMode set to characters.
I tried the  .height property, but it doesnt change as I change the font size

Comment: You could leverage the `ColIsVisible` property.

Comment: You seem to be mixing height and width. Which are you talking about? - The .Height property is the height of the FlexGrid but you're talking about columns which are measured by .ColWidth(ColNo)?

Comment: oops! trying to figure out the number of cell ROWS that are visible. ie the height in rows. The .height property doesn't change as i change the font size and the number of displayable rows changes. I was playing around with .RowIsVisible property, but looping through the entire grid seams like a lot of work. I cant believe there isint an easier way!

Comment: @user1561769 I think looping is your only option.  And unless you have a lot of rows performance should be fine.  Just write a function wrapping RowIsVisible.

Comment: @user1561769 Another possibility would be a calculation involving the .RowHeight property.

Comment: I just wrote a little function. Just thought there would be a property or calculation I could do. Thanks